# Odd threading issue with UITableView images loaded from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, lazy-loading

First up I'm a UI designer getting into Xcode, so please bear with me if i'm a little vague in my description here.

Basically I have a UITableView full of contacts, and each contact has a photo image to the left of the name, pulled from the web via url.. I have implemented lazy loading with the images, but when you scroll through the list, i seem to be getting odd flickering and a really 'laggy' (ie. not smooth) scroll.

I have tried playing around with the `setNeedsDisplay` calls (i know there's a lot of them), but it still seems to wig out.

Have been trying to google some 'best practices' for this, but not sure what's going on here... Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Target: iOS8 in Xcode 6.1

Here's my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if([peep getImage].length > 4) // if URL smaller than 4, it's probably not a valid URL
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if([peep getImage])
        {
            if(![imageCache objectForKey:indexPath])
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[peep getImage]]]];
                    if(image != nil) {
                        [imageCache setObject:image forKey:indexPath];
                        [cell.peepImage setImage:[imageCache objectForKey:indexPath]];
                        [[cell peepImage] setNeedsDisplay];
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [[cell peepImage] setImage:[imageCache objectForKey:indexPath]];
                    [[cell peepImage] setNeedsDisplay];
                });
            }
        }
        [cell.peepImage setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
else
{
    cell.peepImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"defaultuser.jpg"];
}
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Please check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775463/images-in-uitableview-keep-re-loading-and-wrong-images-flash-while-scrolling/26776735#26776735). it will help you lot.you have same issue. that library will manage downloading and caching.

Comment: OP Has a cache already though?

Comment: i think he is using dictionary for caching.

Comment: you can use (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) it is fast and also cache the image once loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the creation of the image on the main thread. By moving it off the main thread your problem should be fixed.

```
if([peep getImage].length > 4) // if URL smaller than 4, it's probably not a valid URL
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if([peep getImage])
        {
            if(![imageCache objectForKey:indexPath])
            {
                // Move image creation here
                __block UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[peep getImage]]]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if(image != nil) {
                        [imageCache setObject:image forKey:indexPath];
                        [cell.peepImage setImage:[imageCache objectForKey:indexPath]];
                        [[cell peepImage] setNeedsDisplay];
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [[cell peepImage] setImage:[imageCache objectForKey:indexPath]];
                    [[cell peepImage] setNeedsDisplay];
                });
            }
        }
        [cell.peepImage setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
else
{
    cell.peepImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"defaultuser.jpg"];
}
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
return cell;
```

Comment: Okay, so it user2369063's feedback did help with the image loading, but it turned out that the lagginess was a separate issue - I had code being executed in `scrollViewDidScroll`:

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
       [self finishSearching];
}`

once i removed this, it worked smoothly. this code was added so that when the keyboard is up (ie. in search), scrolling on the list would dismiss the keyboard... to fix i added in a conditional to only fire this if the keyboard is actually up. Thanks everyone!